# Customise Jira Kanban backlog view with more status

Tags: jira, status, kanban, backlog

The new kanban backlog is great, however it is limited to only viewing the statuses of "backlog" and "todo". Is is possible to configure this somehow? We would like to have a single workflow that covers designers and developers.

```
backlog 
-> design_todo 
-> design_progress 
-> design_done
-> dev_todo
-> dev_progress
-> dev_done
```

We can see backlog and todo in the backlog, but we would also like to see dev_todo. This would mean if a task needs design wor,k this can be done before it is handed over to the developers instead of creating a whole new issue. It also means we don't have yet another column on the board.

It also means the designers board is not filled with developer tasks.
The PM can also move an issue straight to the developers board if it requires no design work.

Comment: You have a different dev and design team and both use the same board? Or different boards filtered by another criteria (component for instance)?

Answer (score 1):

No. I've been in contact with Atlassian about this as I thought the Backlog view was a bit confusing. This is how it works:

In the Kanban board, you can configure which column(s) should be grouped as Backlog in the Backlog view. Your leftmost column in your Kanban view will show on the top in the Backlog view as an own "group".

I also would like more options to configure several groups in the Backlog view.